# How would we retroactively add a personal Campaign Page?

Tags: personal-campaign-pages

When our organization set up our event, we forgot to enable the option for participants to create personal campaign pages. Now, we have several participants who have already registered, but who don't have their personal campaign pages (which they need). How do we add/set up PCPs for them when they've already registered?

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried? eg have you tried going to the PCP front end page and filling in the details, as they would have done if they had used the film themselves?